# .htaccess file so it redirects clean url to include .html extension

Tags: .htaccess

I need to update the below to include .html as well. Currently, it updates a clean URL (no file extension) and adds a .php to the end.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**Example**

```
site.com/folder/file
```

loads

```
site.com/folder/file.php
```

**I need it to do this**

```
site.com/folder/file
```

loads either with HTML or PHP version. HTML being the preferred option if 'both' .html and .php version exist.

```
site.com/folder/file.html
site.com/folder/file.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for presence of corresponding `.php` or `.html` file before rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```